# Asymptotic analysis of code fragment

Tags: big-o, analysis

I need to find the big O running time of the following fragment:

```
sum =0; 
for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
  for (int j=1; j< n/i; j++) {
    sum = sum +j;
  }
}
```

I know the outer loop is O(n) but I am having a problem analyzing the inner loop. I think it's O(log n).

Answer (score 7):

Let's just write this in this pseudo-mathematical style.

```
sum i <- [1..n] (sum j <- [1..n/i] 1)
```

The inner loop (sum) needs

```
n / i
```

iterations, which makes the whole term

```
sum i <- [1..n] (n/i)
```

Simplify the sum according to the distributive law:

```
n * (sum i <- [1..n] (1/i))
```

The inner sum is largely similar to the integral over `1/x`, which is logarithmic.

So `O(n log n)` is right.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach to this is to consider how many steps the algorithm will take.

If you have n elements, you know that the outer loop is going to run at least n times.  So it has to be at least O(n).

How many times does the inner loop have to run for each i?  Does it increase, stay the same or decrease as i increases?

It's clear that the number of steps in the inner loop will decrease as i increases, and more importantly, it decreases non-linearly.  So you know it isn't as bad as O(n^2).

So it's somewhere between O(n) and O(n^2).... a bit more analysis on how the steps decrease in the inner loop should get you there.  EDIT: ... Although it looks like people already gave it away :)

Comment: Actually, it could be O(n^2) (or more properly, Theta(n^2)) even if the number of steps in the inner loop decreases. For instance, think about the case where the inner loop is `n-i` steps (which is the case in the insertion sort algorithm, among others).

Comment: What about `for i in 1..n for j in 1..i ...`? According to your explanation, this isn't `as bad as O(n²)`, because the inner loops range decreases as i increases, but it **actually is** O(n²)

Comment: @jk: Funny, just 17 sec difference^^

Comment: @Dario: didn't you just contradict your answer in this comment?

Comment: @dario and @jk - you guys are correct, I should have said "linearly decreases".

Comment: @Dave: No, my comment describes a completely different for loop, not the one that has been asked for.

Comment: @Dave - no he's pointing out that my explanation is too simplistic.  You can have a smaller inner loop that gets smaller linearly with the outer loop and it's still considered O(n^2).  The number of steps has to be functionally related by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Ok, reaching way back, I understand the discrepancy. Still, I think you got the gist of it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave said, it's O(n log n) because the inner loop is O(log n).

Comment: Wow, that was fast; the question I responded to is gone :)